# Cambiar de activity en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Hola estoy empezando en android studio y quiero cambiar de activity al presionar un botón. El problema es que he probado a usar Intent pero no cambia la activity (el problema no esta en detectar el boton ya que si se representa en la consola el "Si cambia") y android studio no me da ningún error simplemente toco el boton y no pasa nada.

Aquí podéis ver el código para cambiar como he dicho no hay ningún error de sintaxis ni falta de concretar algo, al menos android studio no me da ningún error

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("Si cambia");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RepActivity.class);
        }
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: y por que la etiqueta de [tag:javascript], si no tiene nada que ver? Te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no se porque has puesto la etiqueta de "javascript", deberías haber puesto "Java".

En cuanto a tu problema, te falta añadir a tu código la siguiente instrucción:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Aquí encontrarás la explicación:
[Enlace 1](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?hl=es-419)

Para cualquier duda que te pueda surgir, te recomiendo esta web:
[Enlace 2](https://developer.android.com/?hl=es-419)